# Extend function to prevent paste inside an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to prevent typing everything instead of numbers and points inside a an input field. The problem is that pasting letter or strange things still works. So is there a way to prevent it in my function?

I could do a HTML part like `onpaste="return false;"` but maybe there is a better solution that uses my available function. Thanks for your help!

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 $( document ).on( "keypress keyup paste", "#test", function ( event ) {
  let input = $( this ).val();

  console.log(input);
  console.log(event.which);
  
  if ( ( event.which !== 46 || $( this ).val().indexOf( '.' ) !== -1 ) && ( event.which < 48 || event.which > 57 ) ) {
   event.preventDefault();
  } else if ( ( input.indexOf( '.' ) !== -1 ) && ( input.substring( input.indexOf( '.' ) ).length > 2 ) ) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test"/>
```

**Edit:**

I also found out that the sign `^` still works too but has no event? How is this possible?

The idea is to only allow numbers with points and two decimals like `22222.22` for example.

**Edit 2:**

Input type number is not working because it allows more than just numbers and points.

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow below code handles ctrlX, ctrlV, ^, and allows decimal input

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
let old = input.value
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!this.checkValidity()) {
    this.value = old
  } else {
    old = this.value
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d+(\.[\d]{0,2})?"/>
```

---

For dynamically added input (by using event delegation) we could store the old attribute on the input itself

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( document ).on( "input", "input.decimals", function ( event ) {
  if (!this.checkValidity()) {
    this.value = this.dataset.old || ''
    } else {
      this.dataset.old = this.value
    }
    return true
  })
  const pattern = '\\d+(\\.[\\d]{0,2})?'
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML += `<input class="decimals" type="text" pattern="${pattern}"/>`.repeat(2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I have edited post. You may think about editing the regex yourself for more specific needs though

Comment: Looks cool, makes my life happier now. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Seems to fail for dynamically generated elements. But all in all it's working good!

Comment: Maybe if you have an idea to handle dynamically added inputs, I would be very happy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes since you already do ev delegation, we don't have to add additional eventListener, so problem is just to store the old value (in edited post on the input itself) @Mr.Jo

Comment: Oh perfect! Thanks a lot. I've learned another good thing from you :)

Comment: I actually learnt the input event and the beforeinput (yet to come) thanks to your question as well @Mr.Jo ! cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try to explicitly disable *cut, copy, or paste* functionality on targeted element (e.g: `#txtInput` element) using the snippet below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtInput').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

More on how to do this [here: How to prevent pasting into input fields](https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-prevent-pasting-into-input-fields-nn).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the simple solution which is to use `input` of type `number`?

e.g. `<input type="number" />`

There is a caveat, the letter 'e' can be typed, i.e. Euler's Number

Comment: In this case, there is more allowed instead of . and also I need the pattern xxxx in numbers or with decimal places xxx.x or xxx.xx